# How to access the text definition of sql indexes

Tags: indexing, sql-server-2008-r2

I am able to access the text definition of stored procedures, views, triggers and functions from sys.sql_modules.
I want to get the text definition of indexes.

Can somebody help me in getting the text definition of indexes in sql server.

Thanks,
Puneet

Comment: This sounds like its more about server administration than programming. http://serverfault.com/ might be a better place to ask this.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a programming question. Have a look at dba.stackexchange.com instead.

Comment: FYI: this question has now been cross-posted on dba.StackExchange at: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/95339/how-to-access-the-text-definition-of-sql-indexes

Answer (score 0):

The objects that have definitions found in the [sys.sql_modules](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175081.aspx) Catalog View are the only ones that have full definitions, and indexes are not in this group. The [sys.check_constraints](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187388.aspx) and [sys.default_constraints](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173758.aspx) Catalog Views have partial definitions, but again, those aren't indexes. So no, you are not going to find the text definition of indexes.

What you can find, however, is the meta-data related to indexes that can be used to construct the full text definition. You would find that info in the following Catalog Views:

- [sys.indexes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173760.aspx)
- [sys.index_columns](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175105.aspx)
- [sys.columns](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176106.aspx)
- [sys.data_spaces](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190289.aspx)
- [sys.key_constraints](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174321.aspx)
- [sys.xml_indexes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176003.aspx)
- [sys.partition_schemes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189752.aspx)  (*might* be needed for partitioned indexes)

If you need to get this definition programmatically, then you can use SMO:

- [SQL Server Management Objects (SMO) Programming Guide](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162169.aspx)
- [Automated Script-generation with Powershell and SMO](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/database-administration/automated-script-generation-with-powershell-and-smo/)